# ZipArchive won't get all files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filesystem

I am trying to create zip file from specific folder files, it does create the zip file but `.env` file (i guess any file that starts with dot) will not be include in zip files.

`Question`

**How can I add all files from my folder to zip file regardless of their names?**

`code`

```
public function downloadZip($fileName)
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $downloadFolder = 'downloads';
    if (!file_exists($downloadFolder))
    {
        mkdir($downloadFolder);
    }

    if ($zip->open(public_path($downloadFolder.'/'.$fileName.'.zip'), ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE)
    {
        $files = File::files(public_path($fileName));
        foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
            $relativeNameInZipFile = basename($value);
            $zip->addFile($value, $relativeNameInZipFile);
        }
        $zip->close();
    }
    return response()->download(public_path($downloadFolder.'/'.$fileName.'.zip'));
}
```

`Screenshot`

[image: one]

Comment: The second parameter of [files](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L561) specifies whether or not to include hidden files, please make sure you are using a decent IDE that can properly typehint your calls

Comment: @apokryfos which part should I check?

Comment: @apokryfos this does it `$files = File::files(public_path($fileName), true);` thanks

Comment: @apokryfos you are right, but i do notice on [the contract for laravel 9.x on the docs](https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Filesystem/Filesystem.html#method_files) says the second parameter is for `recursive` - which is odd. and they didn't implement the interface.

Comment: @BagusTesa That looks like a bug, the contract named it recursive but the actual implementation 
 implemented differently.  Given the implementation change (based on the answer) is from 2016 then I think the contract will need to be changed but I guess that needs to be raised in Github

Comment: Actually I misspoke, the Filesystem interface seems to just be coincidentally named the same as the Filesystem class as the latter does not implement this interface.  I can't seem to find anything that implements this interface to be honest.

Answer (score 3):

There is just something about it in this git commit.

[Git commit of laravel](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13555/commits/c8000264e2d75506c21da94f3f3b6855c9c4cb57)

And in this place they debate about it.

[Allow hidden files](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/13555)

You only need to add this to your code:

```
File::allFiles($directory, $hidden = true)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my code to `$files = File::files(public_path($fileName), true);` and its working now.

Comment: The commit that alters `files` (rather than `allFiles`) is actually not the same one but it happened at around the same time as well